# RealmMigrationNeededException when changing Realm model

Tags: android, realm

Whenever I change the model like adding more fields, the app crash with io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException error. This can only be resolved when I uninstalled and reinstalled the app.

Any suggestion to do migration? I am using only the default instance.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce This question was asked a long time before the said duplicate you marked.

Comment: The other question's accepted answer is better than this one, Technically I linked a bunch of questions together based on that regardless of date of asking.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should be able to find the information you need here:

https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#migrations

> Just changing your code to the new definition will work fine, if you
>   have no data stored on disk under the old database schema. But if you
>   do, there will be a mismatch between what Realm sees defined in code &
>   the data Realm sees on disk, so an exception will be thrown.

Comment: Thanks xBroak. Do you know how we can avoid that?

Comment: If you don't care about the data in the Realm, you can just delete the Realm file and open a new instance. That will automatically create a new instance with the right schema. If you do care about the data you need to write a migration block. You can see more details in our Migration example: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/tree/master/examples/migrationExample

Comment: Hi @kodingralph Like Christian linked too, Click the link to the sample code on Realms Migration section which will show you how to instigate a migration for circumstances exactly such as yours.

Comment: Thanks guys.. I saw it previously, but it's not easy to understand without explanation. I think I'll take a look at it again though..

Answer (score 20):

If you don't have any problem in loosing your old data then you can delete Realm Configuration and create new one.

```
Realm realm = null;

                    try {
                       realm = Realm.getInstance(MainActivity.this);
                    } catch (RealmMigrationNeededException r) {
                        Realm.deleteRealmFile(MainActivity.this);
                        realm = Realm.getInstance(MainActivity.this);
                    }
```

OR

```
RealmConfiguration config2 = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this)
                .name("default2") 
                .schemaVersion(3) 
                .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded() 
                .build(); 


        realm = Realm.getInstance(config2);
```

you have to do `Migration` if you don't want to loose your data please see this example [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/tree/master/examples/migrationExample/src/main).

Comment: deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded lines delete all my records of all schemas

Answer (score 3):

Realm migrations in 0.84.2 are changed quite a bit, the key points on making a realm (0.84.2) migration work for me were understanding that:

- The schemaVersion is always 0 when your app has a realm db without
  specifying the schemaVersion. Which is true in most cases since you
  probably start using the schemaVersion in the configuration once you
  need migrations & are already running a live release of your app.
- The schemaVersion is automatically stored and when a fresh install of your app occurs and you are already on schemaVersion 3, realm
  automatically checks if there are exceptions, if not it sets the
  schemaVersion to 3 so your migrations aren't run when not needed.
  This also meens you don't have to store anything anymore in
  SharedPreferences.
- In the migration you have to set all values of new columns when the type is not nullable, ...
- Empty Strings can be inserted but only when setting convertColumnToNullable on the column